# Magento2: How to redirect to payment gateway using api

Tags: magento2, api, payment-gateway

I am new to Magento and want to implement payment gateway with 3rd party.
I am using credcommerce module creater but it works with offline.

Can someone guide me so that I can develope Payment gateway.

I want to use m-paisa by Vodafone

**request pattern will be  like**

```
Send API call to https://pay.mpaisa.vodafone.com.fj/API
API call to provide as parameters the following
- URL for the checkout page
- Transaction id
- Amount
- Client ID
- Item details
https://pay.mpaisa.vodafone.com.fj/API?url=<YOURDOMAIN>
&&tID=<TRANSACTIONID>
&&amt=<AMOUNT>
&&cID=<CLIENTID>
&&iDet=<ITEMDETAILS>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use below link for the guideline of the adding new payment method on your project.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/payments-integrations/base-integration/integration-intro.html